# Using Current Probe to measure fast pulsed currents

Tags: power, current, current-measurement

I'm working on a circuit that charges up a capacitor bank to around 72V and then discharges it into a spark gap. I would like to measure the current through the spark gap. These pulses are ~20usec in duration, peak at around 70-100A and repeat at ~5kHz.

I am concerned that the inductance in the cables will make it such that the spark gap is continuing to get significant current even after my output switch has been turned off. I was hoping to use a current probe to look at the output current waveform.

I was planning to use a current probe like this:
[https://www.amazon.com/Current-CP2100B-measurable-70-7Arms-Measuring/dp/B09NQ7GTVY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09NQ7GTVY)

But the datasheet (https://www.micsig.com/uploads/MicsigCP2100CurrentProbeDatasheet_1661755307.pdf) shows a heavy derating curve past ~200kHz:
[image]

Do I need to be worried about this causing issues/burning out the current probe? Would it be better to use a diff probe + a shunt resistor to make this measurement?

Comment: You might have some issues depending on the slew rates. Maybe look into Pearson's wide-bandwidth current transformers?

Comment: See also [Rogowski coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogowski_coil).

Comment: Would these solutions work for effectively measuring the low frequency (~5kHz) components of this and have enough bandwidth for the higher frequency stuff too?

Comment: I almost don't believe it has a bandwidth of 2.5MHz for only $400.

Comment: Please provide a link to the data sheet of the probe.

Comment: It's pretty sparse but here it is: https://www.micsig.com/uploads/MicsigCP2100CurrentProbeDatasheet_1661755307.pdf